# MvvmCross nuget package and MvvmCross.Core clarifications

Tags: mvvmcross

Am I supposed to be adding a reference to MvvmCross v6.0.1 which should include MvvmCross.Core, MvvmCross,Platform or am I supposed to be adding individual references to each of these NuGet packages?

MvvmCross is at version 6.0.1 but MvvmCross.Core is at 5.7.0 including MvvmCross.Platform, which are the NuGet packages installed by the MvvmCross Visual Studio template.

Answer (score 0):

> With MvvmCross 6 there are some changes to the NuGet packages. The
>   following packages are obsolete and included in the main MvvmCross
>   package:
>
> - `MvvmCross.Core`
> - `MvvmCross.Platform`
> - `MvvmCross.Binding`

MvvmCross 6 release [blog post](https://www.mvvmcross.com/mvvmcross-6.0.0-release/#nuget-packages).

Therefore you no longer need these packages.

There is also the [migration guide](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/upgrading/upgrade-to-mvvmcross-60) with may you help with updating your project.